# Python 3.4 : continue function after try and except

Tags: python-3.x, exception

## Question

I am currently pulling data from yahoo finance.  When using try and except, the function stops after the error has been reached.  How can I continue the function after the except statement to pull the remaining data for stocks in the index?

```
index = sp500


def yhooKeyStats():

try:

    for eachStock in index:
        isUrl = 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q/is?s='+eachStock+'+Income+Statement&annual'
        bsUrl = 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q/bs?s='+eachStock+'+Balance+Sheet&annual'
        cfUrl = 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q/cf?s='+eachStock+'+Cash+Flow&annual'


        def bsYhooStats(url):
            req = urllib.request.Request(url)
            resp = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
            respData = resp.read()
            dRespData = respData.decode('utf-8')

            gw = dRespData.split('Goodwill</td><td align="right">')[1].split('&nbsp;&nbsp')[0]

            if len(gw) < 14:
                gw = gw
            else:
                gw = '-'

            return gw

        print(eachStock, bsYhooStats(bsUrl))

except IndexError:
    pass
```

yhooKeyStats()

## Output

MMM 7,050,000
ABT 10,067,000
ABBV 5,862,000
ACN 2,395,894
ACE -
ACT 24,521,500
ADT 3,738,000
AES 1,458,000
AET 10,613,200
AFL -

Comment: You can put the try/except inside the loop.

Comment: That was too simple... Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put the `try/except` *inside* the loop. One of several possibilities:

```
for eachStock in index:
    ...
    try:
        def bsYhooStats(url):
            ...
            return gw if len(gw) < 14 else '-'
        print(eachStock, bsYhooStats(bsUrl))
    except IndexError:
        pass
```